# Select Direct Child of $(this) in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I know that I can use $('img', this) to select all img elements in $(this).

In my current case I am trying to manipulate only DIRECT child images of $(this).

Is there a selector for that??

Answer (score 39):

```
$(this).find('> img')
```

[Read this](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: This will be deprecated in a future release. http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: @Precipitous: I've updated the code snippet. Note that the use of the child-selector is not going to be deprecated, but only the use of the context argument to the constructor like this is to be deprecated. `$(selector, context)` is currently a redirect to `$(context).find(selector)` which is recommended way.

Comment: Note that `.find(selector)` and `.children(filter)` are not the same. `.find()` is a general "do it all" css selector based search algorithm (powered by Sizzle"), whereas `.children()` does not use the selector engine but gets the direct children of the current element(s), and can optionally reduce that set to the ones matching a selector. When dealing only with direct children, then `.children()` is recommended.

Comment: @Krinkle do you know if the context argument is still slated to be deprecated?  I don't see anything in the docs indicating that, although I remember seeing that somewhere at some point.  It may be that since you commented that the team decided it was handy and to not deprecate.  Anyone have a current line on this arg?

Answer (score 11):

```
$(this).children('img');
```

See also: http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 4):

```
$(this).find('> img');
```

I got this thanks to Gabi's answer

edit:

people dont downvote me come on this was Gabi's answer until yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4444131/revisions)

```
$(this).find('> img', this);
```

so why the hell are you downvoting my answer while it was like this all the time and answers the OP question ?!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: sorry but I think this answers 'I am trying to manipulate only DIRECT child images of $(this). Is there a selector for that??' does it not? does my answer not select direct child images of $(this)?